# how to pass xml data on button click to some other page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

am getting data from data.xml on button click, which i want to disaply on some other page on same button click. It means, on button click i should navigate to some other page and display data.please note that am **not** using 
 **jquery Mobile.**

```
$('#findPO').click(function() {

    $.get('data.xml',function(data){
        /* window.location.href = 'Search_Result.html'; */
        $('#resultContainer').empty();
        $(data).find('project').each(function(){
            var $project = $(this);
            var html = '<div class="data">';                      
            html += '<h3>' + $project.attr('company') + '</h3>';
            html += '<div class="product">' + $project.find('product').text() + '</div>';                   
            html += '<div class="type">' + $project.find('type').text() + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="members">' + $project.find('members').text() + '</div>';

            $('#resultContainer').append(html);

        });                        
    });
    return false;
});
```

I have to use only javascript or jquery html and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On button click, create the html you wish to send to the other page (as a string) and stick it into a variable. Then, create a form with an input field with, for example, `name="input_to_send"` and stick the HTML (string var) into that field:

```
$('#input_to_send').val(strHTML2Send);
```

Then, use jQuery's `.submit()` method to submit the form to the destination page.

The form's `action="somepage.php"` attribute will, of course, contain the name of the destination page, and also `method="POST"`.

So, the $.get() routine would look like this:

```
$.get('data.xml',function(data){
    /* window.location.href = 'Search_Result.html'; */
    $('#resultContainer').empty();
    $(data).find('project').each(function(){
        var $project = $(this);
        var html = '<div class="data">';                      
        html += '<h3>' + $project.attr('company') + '</h3>';
        html += '<div class="product">' + $project.find('product').text() + '</div>';                   
        html += '<div class="type">' + $project.find('type').text() + '</div>';
        html += '<div class="members">' + $project.find('members').text() + '</div>';

        $('#resultContainer').append(html);

        var myForm = '<form id="form2send" action="other_php_file.php" method="POST">';
        myForm += '<input name="input_to_send" type="hidden" value="' +html+ '" /></form>';

        $('#some_spare_empty_div').html(myForm);
        $('#form2send').submit();

    });                        
});
```

On the receiving end, you will receive the html you sent like this:

```
<?php
    $h = $_POST['input_to_send'];
    echo '<div id="put_it_here">';
    echo $h;
    echo '</div>';
```

Do you need a larger code example? Judging from the code in your question above, I don't think you do.

Comment: what this PHP code will do. anyother solution without PHP. or can you pls eloborate. as of now on button click page navigates but with empty data.

Comment: (1) Have you worked with HTML forms before? (2) In the past, how have you used data from a POSTed form? (3) What back-end programming language do you have? Note: If you are on a CPANEL-based hosting account, you probably have PHP available.

Comment: With PHP, when you receive POSTed data, you receive a number of variables that contain data. That is the purpose of a POST - to send data.  In the example above, the variable's NAME is `input_to_send` and the data is stored in `$_POST['input_to_send']`. The PHP command `echo()` prints data onto the screen (or into the DOM).

Comment: yes. am new to web application. but i just quick fix the issue. as i am showing on same page as inline. by making div show and hide.